# Болоченое-заболоченное болото (кол-во н, имеемое словом)

Tags: орфография

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я, прочитав эту статью (1-е примечание), лично-прелично Розенталём-то-с написанную, сейчас предполагаю, что следующие сочетания нужно все, несмотря на то что второе причастие в них-то имеет-таки приставку, писать все с одной таки *н,* а имеено: *болоченое-заболоченое болото, готовленая-заготовленая капуста, селеный-засоленые огурчики, порваная-разпорванная подушка.*

Я, однако, хочу, чтобы Вы мне сказали-таки, правильно ли я-то понимаю эту, по-розентальски написанную таки, статью. (Может быть, это правило применяется только к словосочетаниям, где второе-то слово имеет приставку *пере-* и никакую иную?)

Comment: Видимо, только с приставкой пере- и только в подобных словах с дефисным написанием, потому что переглаженные.

Comment: И вообще такие словосочетания, как вы написали, не очень сочетаются, точнее очень-преочень не сочетаются)

Comment: @Pumpkin777 Интересный у Вас язык. Думаю, что надо править: заболоченое болото — тавтология, лучше "место"; селеный — соленые; ра**з**порванная — ра**с**порваная (ра**с**порка, ра**с**порядок); болоченый, распорваный — мне такие слова не попадались.